# constricting scrolling in core-plot

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I would like to have my user scroll inside a CPXYGraph. I have a CPXYGraph as part of a CPHostingLayer, like in the tutorials. I enabled allowsUserInteraction, which is cool and allows scrolling. But I don't want to allow my user to scroll to 'infinity', which it seems like it allows-you can keep dragging further and further away from where the data is on a plot.

How do I constrain this so that the user can only scroll within a certain bounds?

I also enabled masksToBorder, and set the outerBorderPath and innerBorderPath to something arbitarily small, but I saw no changes, so I am not sure how those are supposed to work.

I could not set maskingPath and subLayerMaskingPath because they seem to be read only(no setters), though i feel like these two properties might be what I am looking for.

Anyone has run into this situation? Would be glad if someone could shed some light. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The masking properties only affect the drawing. You need to use the `globalXRange` and `globalYRange` properties of your plot space. These define the maximum range that can be scrolled into view. See the example in CPTestApp.

Comment: eric, this sounds like exactly what I want. I will verify and let you know as I am away right now. Thanks in advance!